# Jenkins pipeline stage will not download artifact from our repository

Tags: jenkins

I have a stage that needs to download an artifact (a zip file) from the repository.
The file is in the repository and the group, name, and version are correct.
The output from the Jenkins console states that it is downloading.  But the error states that the file specified was not found
THis is the error:

> ava.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the
> file specified    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)  at
> java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)

This is the stage where it should download

```
steps {
        echo "Download from Nexus: " + "$APP_GROUP" + " " + "$APP_NAME" + " " + "${params.VERSION}"
        script {
            downloadNexusArtifact groupId: "$APP_GROUP",
                    artifactId: "$APP_NAME", 
                    repo:"$RELEASE_REPO_NAME",
                    version: "${params.VERSION}",
                    release: true,
                    extension: "zip"
        }
        echo "Zip downloaded from Nexus"
    }
```

The echo shows the correct App Group, name and version.
I have used this method in many other jenkins pipelines. But I can't find any reference to it.
The zip file is large.  It is 34 MB.

This pipeline deploys an application that runs on a Windows Server.
The agent is for Windows.
The other pipelines are for deploying java application on a linux servers.

Any ideas has to why this step does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out why this was failing...
the agent was a windows agent and the download method needed to be unix.
I set the agent to our unix agent in this step and it work.